# Vue.js Can't check if the user is signed in computed properties

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I want to check if the user is logged in in Firebase but I can't do it in computed properties.

What I want to do is to show a form depending on whether the user is signed in.

```
    <v-form
      ref="form"
      v-if="isSignedIn"
      v-model="valid"
      lazy-validation>
    ...

     computed: {
      isSignedIn() {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
          if (user) {
              return true
          } else {
              return false
          }
       })
     },
```

Even if I use observer, the property is still `undefined`.

However, this way works. (I checked if the user is signed in in method and assign the result into a variable.)

```
<v-form
  ref="form"
  v-if="flag"
  v-model="valid"
  lazy-validation>
...

methods: {
    isSignedIn() {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
          if (user) {
              this.flag = true
          } else {
              this.flag = false
          }
       })    
    }
},
mounted() {
    this.isSignedIn()
}
```

What am wrong with the first way?

Comment: I think the second approach is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more detail on your Vue.js component code it is difficult to help you.

However, note that the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users) explains that:

> The recommended way to get the current user is by setting an observer
>   on the Auth object
>
> ```
> firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
>   if (user) {
>       // User is signed in.   
>   } else {
>       // No user is signed in.   
>   } 
> });
> ```

Comment: Sorry my explanation was too lazy. I updated it. Please take a look.

Comment: "A computed property will only re-evaluate when some of its reactive dependencies have changed.", see https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html. In your case there is no reactive dependencies in your `isSignedIn()` property.